# Use set.seed() with foreach() in R

Tags: r, for-loop, foreach, random-seed

I am currently running a simulation using a for loop in R, but want to switch over to a foreach loop since it is faster. I use set.seed() in the for loop, and would like to use this again with foreach so I can obtain identical results.

For example, suppose I have

```
x <- c()
for (i in 1:10){
    set.seed(i)
    x[i] <- rnorm(1)
}
```

How can I do this same thing using foreach? I don't think this works:

```
x <- foreach(i = 1:10, ...) %dopar% {set.seed(i) ... }
```

Comment: This question has been asked before, even sometime in the last month. You can find some answers on other posts.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Nevermind, what I had actually does work! I tried it a while ago and thought it didn't, but I was clearly mistaken...

Comment: Use the doRNG package if you need reproducible random numbers in parallelized code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
library (foreach)

fn<-function(i)
{
  set.seed(i)
  y <- rnorm(1)
  return(y)
}

x<-foreach(i=1:10) %do% fn(i)
print(x)
```